# ¿Cómo brindar permisos de escritura y lectura a un S3 bucket de aws a alguien que no sea usuario de AWS?

Tags: c++, aws

He estado teniendo este problema y no sé como solucionarlo.
Contexto: La idea principal, era hacer un proyecto en UE4 donde pueda subir imagenes a un bucket en AWS para aumentar la velocidad de carga.
Todo funciona perfecto. Sin embargo, solo funciona si tengo las credenciales en forma local del usuario IAM con los respectivos permisos.
Pero si esto es un proyecto de un videojuego, la idea es que cualquiera pueda enviar una imagen al bucket, no debería necesitar una cuenta en aws.

Bueno, como decía, si mando una imagen con las credenciales locales, todo funciona perfecto.
Pero sin las credenciales me lanza el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no sé como hacer que el bucket tenga la flexibilidad de escritura y hago énfasis, flexibilidad de escritura para personas sin cuenta en AWS.
Así que si alguien puede ayudarme, lo agradecería.

Comment: añade el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de interactuar directamente con S3, crea un servicio, con AWS Lambda, por ejemplo, que haga de intermediario entre S3 y tu software. De esta forma, con que la lambda tenga credenciales para escribir en S3 ya será suficiente.

Eso sí, tendrás que buscar la forma de evitar que alguien que consiga acceder a esa lambda pueda empezar a añadir contenido a tu S3 libremente (quizás filtrando extensiones, tamaño del archivo, pidiendo algún tipo de credencial que te inventes...), ya que vas a ser tú el que pague por los gastos de almacenamiento

Answer (score 0):

Pues puedes configurar el bucket para que tenga acceso público para lectura y escritura en los ACL del bucket.

Si revisas la [documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#permissions), se ve que los ACL (*access control lists*, listas de control de acceso) permiten hacer lo que deseas. Hay unos *canned ACL*, que son como opciones predefinidas. Hay una llamada *public-read-write* que, bajo tu propio riesgo, permite que cualquiera que logre encontrar el bucket pueda leer y escribir en él.

De nuevo, ni AWS ni nadie lo recomendaría (a menos que quieras ofrecer alojamiento gratuito a spam, bots y mugre variopinta)